# tftp times out on localhost

Tags: localhost, timeout, hosts-file, tftp

On the same server, I can't connect to my in.tftp over localhost name:

```
$ tftp localhost -c put test.file && echo Sent\!
Transfer timed out.

$ tftp 127.0.0.1 -c put test.file && echo Sent\!
Sent!
```

Does the tftp centos client ignore the hosts file?  Other things seem to work as expected:

```
$ echo quit|nc localhost 25
220 my.ser.ver ESMTP Postfix
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: What is "localhost" resolving to?

Comment: If I ping localhost it shows 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Strace of the time out also indicates the proper IP conversion takes place: http://snipt.org/Giho1/#expand

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [strace](http://snipt.org/Giho1/#expand) of the failing command, it turns out that 'localhost' was resolving to '::1' which was a secondary IPv6 entry in the hosts file.   My xinet.d/tftp definition had a flag for IPv4 only.

The solution is to either remove the IPv6 hosts entry or remove the IPv4 from the tftp server.  This now works:

```
$ tftp localhost -c put test.file && echo Sent\!
Sent!
```

Comment: Or have the TFTP server listening on both IPv4 and IPv6. Or IPv6 only. It's a very bad idea to remove the entry from the hosts file.

Comment: Yep. That's what I suspected.

Comment: This just happened to me or Oracle Linux 7.  Commented out the IPv6 localhost entry in `/etc/hosts` and it works fine now.